# System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch() is launching debugging window in another session in RDP

Tags: .net, windows, debugging, rdp

I have created a Windows service and using `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` in `.Net` to debug it. Apart from me, there is another user who is connected to RDP and working on this machine. Problem is, sometime when I start service, it will open debugging window in other user's session.

This doesn't happen all the time but sometime. No idea why it happens that way and how can I make sure that debugger attach window opens in my session only.